# OSPF Between Compute Engine CSRs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cisco-ios

I am trying to run OSPF between two CSRs in GCP Compute Engine. The CSRs are deployed in the same project and are only for testing purposes right now. I am not able to get OSPF to form between the routers and also not able to get a tunnel to form between the routers.

The tunnel interfaces are up/up, but I am not able to ping between the tunnel interfaces. Currently, I have all firewall rules set to allow any any between the routers. I can ping, ssh, etc. between the hosts, but cannot form dynamic routing or GRE tunnels.

Is this something that is being blocked by Google?

**Router1**

```
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address 192.168.0.32 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid

interface Tunnel1
 ip address 172.31.254.1 255.255.255.252
 ip mtu 1400
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 192.168.0.20
```

**Router2**

```
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address 192.168.0.20 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid

interface Tunnel1
 ip address 172.31.254.2 255.255.255.252
 ip mtu 1400
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 192.168.0.32
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, this is a routing problem. Include information about the VPCs, VPC route tables and the instance internal route tables.

Comment: Have a look at the [VPC documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications) "VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic. They do not support broadcast, [multicast](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast),..." and it could be the cause of your issue with OSPF.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [firewall documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in) "Google Cloud doesn't allow certain IP protocols, such as [GRE](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation), within a VPC network. For more information, see [always blocked traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic).". So, you're issue with GRE is intended behaviour and you should you other tunnel proptocols.

Comment: Ok. That is what I was worried about. I didn't see the always blocked traffic bit. I knew multicast was blocked but was hoping GRE was allowed. It was for network testing.